# Running Next.js application in dev mode, a runtime error occurs, saying "ReferenceError: Cannot access X before initialization"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-devtools

I am using next.js version 13.4. I made a Provider using ContextAPI in react(, let's say it's `AuthContext`) and wrap the whole application with it in `RootLayout` component. The `RootLayout` is placed in `app/layout.tsx`.

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <GlobalErrorBoundary>
          <AuthProvider>{children}</AuthProvider>
        </GlobalErrorBoundary>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

There's no error in build time but **when I run `npm run dev`, the browser yelled that "Unhandled Runtime Error" occurs. And saying, "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'AuthContext' before initialization".**

When I build the application and `npm run start`, it works well. **It only happens when I run `npm run dev`.** What's worse is this runtime error happens randomly, quite often, though.

When I look into the react's devTool, theres' an error in `ReactDevOverlay`, which has a children named `<DevRootNotFoundBoundary />`. The error message is saying, "The above error occurred in the  component".
[image]

**Edit:**

Here is a simple version of the `Auth.tsx` (for declaring ContextAPI) code:

```
"use client";

export const AuthContext =
    createContext<AuthContextType | null>(null);

export const AuthProvider = ({
    children,
}: PropsWithChildren) => {
    const [token, setToken] =
        useStateWithLocalStorage<AuthTokenType>("token");
    const newToken = useTokenRefresh(token);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (newToken === undefined) {
            return;
        }

        setToken(newToken);
    }, [newToken]);

    useMemo(() => {
        if (token === null) {
            return;
        }
        addTokenToHttpClient(token);
    }, [token]);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={{
                token,
                setToken,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useAuthContext = () => {
    const context: AuthContextType | null = useContext(
        AuthContext
    );

    if (context === null) {
        throw new Error();
    }

    return context;
};
```

You might want to know the inside of `useStateWithLocalStorage` used above. The possible errors occuring when referring to `localStorage` in the server is covered by below logic.

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    return localStorage.getItem(key);
}
```

**Edit:**

I found a suspicious point in codebase, but cannot figure out the exact reason of it. Can anyone help me with this?

My `Auth.tsx` file is under `app/contexts/withLocalStorage/` directory. Inside this directory there are 2 different Context files other than `Auth.tsx` file and plus, `index.ts` file. Every variables of Context files are exported through `index.ts`.

Below is `index.ts`.

```
"use client";

export * from "./Example1";
export * from "./Example2";
export * from "./Auth";
```

The only difference in `Auth` and other 2 example files is, in `Auth.tsx`, it's using `useEffect` and `useMemo`. When I comment out the line above `export * from "./Auth";` in `index.ts`, the **ERROR DISAPPEARS!**.

It seems `index.ts` is trying to import modules in server-side. But a Context file using React's client-side API is not created yet at that time. `"use client";` directive in `index.ts` doesn't work in this case. But why? Or if so, is there any workaround to use `useEffect` or `useMemo` in context files?

Comment: Please show the content of AuthContext file.

Comment: Are you using useContext in the same file as Provider?

Comment: I edited by adding AuthContext file. Please tell me if you need any other parts of code more.

Comment: @FuNianWong sorry, I don't get it. But maybe don't? I declared it in other file not app/layout.tsx

Comment: @kyuhyun if possible, paste the code where you call the useAuthContext() and also the file path.

Comment: @ FuNianWong Now I get what you mean, thanks. 
It is called on a hook, named `useSignin` which is called in `app/(auth)/signin/page.tsx`.
And in 2 layout files. `app/(service)/layout.tsx` and `app/(user)/layout.tsx`.